# Calculating the Up-vector for glmLookAt?

Tags: opengl, glm-math

I have a directional light and I want to generate a view matrix for this light (using glm lookAt()). I know the light direction and its position, but how would I go about getting the up vector with only those parameters? (the cross-product requires the left vector aswell, but I only have the forward vector...). Is it always (0, 1, 0)?

Answer (score 0):

You want an orthonormal basis `(V,U,R)` where `V` is the view direction (light direction in your case), `U` is the up vector and `R` is the vector orthogonal to `U` and `V`.
`(V,U,R)` + your light position `O` define the camera.

To define this basis you need 2 vectors, for instance `U` and `V`, and the third is deduced as `cross(U,V)`. That's why glmLookAt needs 2 vectors and not just the `V` vector.

If you only have `V` then there are infinite possibilities for `U`: `O+U` define the whole unit circle centered at `O`.

You can pick a random `U` by taking a random vector `X != V && X != -V` then `U` can be computed as:

```
U = cross(normalize(V), normalize(X))
```

However for different `X` the rendering with that camera will be different!

If you're using this for shadow mapping, try setting you frustum so that for any `U` the shadowed scene is well covered (again, different frustum and `U` settings produce different amount of aliasing).

Comment: I'm not sure I follow - pick a random vector to get a random result each shadow pass? Surely there is only one correct vector?

Comment: Any vector orthogonal to the light direction is a valid UP vector. A random UP vector (orthogonal to the light direction) can be enough for shadow mapping. If the light dynamically changes over time, a randomly changing UP vector remains valid (but can cause temporal aliasing as the sampling rate slightly changes for different views). When the light doesn't change use the same UP vector and don't recompute the shadow map

Comment: I don't know what do you mean by shadow pass but the camera (and other transforms and fixed functions...) associated to the light must be exactly the same when building the shadow map and during shadow comparisons